# CSS Page Pagination Style

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, chakra-ui

### CSS Style Overview

I'm attempting to design a CSS style that includes a customer section on the left side, the selected customer details on the right side, and pagination buttons at the bottom. You can refer to the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdmZA.png) for visualization.

### Try to achive

> My goal is to enable scrolling within the customer container so that the content can expand as needed. However, I want the pagination buttons to always remain visible beneath the customer container, even when scrolling, and stay at the bottom of the page. please give me an idea how can i achive this kind of layout.

```
===========================
=                    |  u =
=                    |  s =
=   N Customers      |  e =
=                    |  r =
= pagination Buttons |    =
===========================
```

**Using chakra ui with next-js.**

```
import { Flex, Heading, Input, InputGroup, Stack, Text, Avatar, Box, Center, Divider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import ContentHeader from "./design/ContentHeader";
import WhiteButton from "./design/WhiteButton";

export default function Customers() {
  return (
    <Flex width="100%" flexDir="column" gap="1rem" height="100%">
      <ContentHeader description="" heading="Total Customers (50)" />
      <Flex gap="0.1rem">
        <CustomersList />
        <Flex flex={1} bg="var(--grey-color)" rounded="lg" height={'auto'} justifyContent={'center'}>
            <Flex py = {'2rem'} flexDir={'column'} alignContent={'center'} gap={'1rem'}>
                <Center>
                    <Avatar size="xl" name="Kent Dodds" src="link" />
                </Center>
                <Center flexDir={'column'}>
                    <Heading fontSize={'xl'}>Kent C Dodds</Heading>
                    <Text fontSize={'sm'}>Owner at Corsa Auto Rentals</Text>
                </Center>

                <Divider color={'white'}/>

                <Center flexDir={'column'}>
                    <Heading fontSize={'xl'}>Email Address</Heading>
                    <Text fontSize={'md'}>ethan@ethanduran.com</Text>
                </Center>

                <Center gap={'1rem'} flexWrap={'wrap'}>
                    <WhiteButton>Message</WhiteButton>
                    <WhiteButton>Edit</WhiteButton>
                    <WhiteButton>Documents</WhiteButton>
                </Center>
            </Flex>
        </Flex>
      </Flex>
      {/*pagination bar*/}
      <WhiteButton>pagination button 1</WhiteButton>
      <WhiteButton>pagination button 2</WhiteButton>
    </Flex>
  );
}

const CustomersList = () => {
  return (
    <Flex flex={3} width={'100%'}>
      <Stack spacing={4} padding="1rem" width={'100%'} maxH={'100%'}>
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
        <CustomerData />
      </Stack>
    </Flex>
  );
}

const CustomerData = ({ }) => {
  return (
    <Flex
      background="var(--grey-color)"
      padding="1rem"
      gap="1.5rem"
      flexDir="row"
      rounded="lg"
      overflowX="auto"
    >
      <Avatar size="md" name="Kent Dodds" src="link" />
      <Stack spacing={0}>
        <Text fontSize="lg" whiteSpace="nowrap">
          Kent C Dodds
        </Text>
        <Text fontSize="xs" whiteSpace="nowrap">
          +92 311 628****
        </Text>
      </Stack>

      <Flex gap="1rem" marginLeft="auto">
        {["Vehicles", "Payments", "Referrals"].map((title, idx) => {
          return (
            <Stack key={idx} spacing={0} textAlign="center">
              <Text fontWeight="bold">{title}</Text>
              <Text fontWeight="bold">20</Text>
            </Stack>
          );
        })}
      </Flex>
    </Flex>
  );
}
```

[code link](https://github.com/Zain-ul-din/SupercarAdmin/blob/preview/src/components/Customers.tsx)

[image: Refernce Image]

Comment: @MissSkooter wait let me add

Comment: In your code in which component can we find this pagination bar?

Comment: added in `Customers` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your shared code, could not get the pagination component.

However this can be achived by applying `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` to the wrapper div *(say .list)* of `<List />` and `<Pagination/>` component.

And if the list can be smaller sometimes and you want the pagination bar to always be at the bottom of the page, add `flex:grow: 1;` to the wrapper div *(.list)* of `<List />` and `<Pagination />`

Checkout the similar structured JSFiddle I created. Including the case when list is small:  https://jsfiddle.net/4zqvny5f/2/

Comment: you're code is working but the problem is `100vh` not works on mobile devices

Comment: Oh is it. I asked ChatGPT. this is what it suggested as an equivalent of 100vh in chakra-ui. `<VStack h="100vh" justify="center" align="center"> {...} </VStack>`.

Comment: wait for other answers. if this post will get no more answer i'll accept you're answer

Comment: Hope it resolves the main issue. Let me know if any case is not handled.

Comment: yes, sure i'll ask!

Answer (score 0):

What solves your problem is the `position: fixed;` in CSS.
Supposing that your pagination bar is `div.bar`, add to it the following CSS ruleset:

```css
div.bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  left: 100px;
  right: 100px;
}
```

For sure this is just a Proof of Concept / example, and you can change the values as you want.

Comment: i tried this approach but not working on responsive layouts

Comment: aslo as you can see in image customer content has side bar on it's left